# Is it possible to use OpenGL 4.5 features with latest mesa libraries?

Tags: opengl

I want to use latest OpenGL features on Ubuntu. And I have installed mesa-common-dev but as far as I understand mesa does not support OpenGL 4.5 features. Also how can I use OpenGL via hardware without any API ?

Note : 
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 4.5.13397 Compatibility Profile Context 15.20.1046

Comment: If you want to use the latest OpenGL features, install the lates official drivers for your video card.

Comment: I installed the latest AMD driver. But how I can use proprietary libraries when I linking libgl ?

Comment: If everything is installed correctly the amd drivers should be used automatically.

Comment: see http://mesamatrix.net/

Comment: @user237160, Maybe you've figured this by now, but I was having the same problem with `glBufferStorage` function, which is first specified in OpenGL 4.4 and though I had proprietary Nvidia OpenGL library installed the mesa library was taking priority over it while compiling with `-lGL` and gave me linking errors. 

I had to explicitly mention the library path with gcc option `-L/directory/containing/Nvidia's/libGL.so` _before_ `-lGL` so it links with Nvidia's library. You can do a `locate libGL.so` to locate your proprietary library.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to use latest OpenGL features on Ubuntu. And I have installed mesa-common-dev but as far as I understand mesa does not support OpenGL 4.5 features.

All that matters is, that your actual OpenGL implementation supports the profile you want. The Linux ABI on OpenGL is pinned to OpenGL-1.2 (LSB5 has been released recently, so expect upcoming  distribution releases to follow it, which bumped it to OpenGL-2.1).

Anything that goes beyond the ABI requirements is done through the extension mechanism. I.e. use load function pointers through *…GetProcAddress* and introduce new tokens with a `glext.h`. This processes has been repacked into OpenGL extension wrapper-loader libraries like GLEW.

The stuff mesa-common-dev provides is what's written down in the Linux LSB ABI specs… in a vendor neutral way, so you can compile your program using mesa-common-dev stuff, but it will work with the NVidia or AMD/ATI drivers as well.

> Also how can I use OpenGL via hardware without any API ?

By definition you can't. OpenGL is an API. If you remove the API you remove OpenGL. If your intention is working the naked GPU on the bare metal, well, that would boil down to writing a full driver. In a few weeks/months Vulkan will be released and this gets you much closer to the GPU than OpenGL.